Where can I put money so that I can transfer it easily?
My bank (the Postal bank) has blocked me from transferring money through their website. I do not know why - they do not answer the phone. The only way I can transfer money is physically go to the post office and fill a physical form. This is very inconvenient, since I am currently working on a project and need to transfer money frequently.
I would like to make a one-time transfer of a large amount of money from my account to an account on some other platform, from which I can easily make transfers through a website. But I do not want to pay extra fees on this extra account.
I thought of opening an account in a digital bank (e.g. One-Zero, Pepper), where there is no fee; but I read many negative opinions about them.
Is there another platform where this is possible? E.g. is it possible to put money on a Paypal account, or another similar online platform?
I do not need any sophisticated banking services - only the option to transfer money between accounts.

Product recommendations are generally off-topic as they routinely go stale and become outdated. Have you considered a regular commercial bank? The Postal bank is generally intended for what is called "unbanked" population, with very rudimentary services.

Who are you transferring the money to? Do you know them? This sounds like a scam and your bank may be protecting you from falling for it.

Can you physically go to the post office and ask why you can't transfer how you used to? How would you transfer to Paypal if you can't transfer to other bank accounts?

@JohnFx Yes, I know them. And the website does not let me even start the transfer - even before I write the details of the recipient.

@Nosjack I can physically go to the post office and make a transfer; I cannot make the transfer through the application. The officers in the post office do not know why I am blocked in the application - they only know to do very specific jobs.

Why don’t you just open another bank account with online banking and transfer the money there? Do you need to make payments only to other Israeli people/businesses or do you need to make payments abroad? Is your account a business or personal account? If a personal account, are you using it for business purposes? Have you maybe exceeded any limits? What error message do you get?

@jcaron Opening another bank account incurs fees, which I would like to avoid, as I only need transfers.
